# Is there any way to run a browser with Active X control in Android?

Tags: android, internet-explorer, com, activex

Probably a stupid question, but ...

I want a cheap computer for a single purpose - to connect to and interact with a web site which requires MS Internet Explorer.

I say that it "requires MS Internet Explorer", but I am not savvy enough to say if that is 100% true. What I can say is that the browser uses an Active X control to interact with a COM DLL on the PC.

I can't change that - is there any way that I can do it in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/open-active-android-browser/). It's not possible.

Because it's a Windows only framework.

<strike>Edit: [This one](http://www.computeractive.co.uk/ca/pc-help/2152003/activex-android-phone-home-cctv) might also help you.</strike>